# Storing recaptcha verification in a session (Security)

Tags: php, security, session, recaptcha

I have added google recaptcha verification in a form.
Form can be submitted multiple times by the same user.
So instead of verifying recaptcha everytime on page refresh , what I am doing is once the user verified the recaptcha first time , I store it in a session variable something like `$_SESSION['user_verified'] = "yes"` and doesn't show the recaptcha next time on page refresh , so that user doesn't have to verify everytime.

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION['user_verified']) ){
        //Show recaptcha
    }
```

Is it safe? Do i need to worry about the BOTS?
Thanks

Comment: How much time do you plan to make the test result valid, before you test the client again?

Comment: Haven't given any thought about it yet , I am more concerned about the approach.
It would be around 20 minutes.

Comment: I think this is more about your application and how sensitive it is to requests made by bots. For example you will see recaptcha **every** time you query [whois.icann.org](https://whois.icann.org/en/lookup?name=stackoverflow.com). But no need for bot test for someone or somebot requesting to see you website home page.

Comment: regarding the time, again it depends in your application. In my application I do your approach but I make the test result valid for a week not 20 minutes, so it's not annoying to my human clients.

Comment: Please note that recaptcha alone is not enough for protecting you against bots, because an attacker will resolve the recaptcha one or couple of times, and bingo your system will accept thousands of bot requests. You need to test **The speed of the requests originated from a single IP**